# Meditation to simulate Near-death Experience

Tags: meditation, meditation-recommendation, tantra

Namaste, Namo Buddhaya.

I'm here in my personal pursuit to understand *death* and *soul* from various perspectives.
A few days back I was reading texts on life, death, and reincarnation and got to know that there exist some meditations that cause *OBEs* (Out-of-body Experiences), an important part of NDEs (Near-death Experiences).

Biologists and doctors while simulating NDEs in labs concluded that a very large portion of people recall OBE experiences. The [official Wikipedia page on NDEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-death_experience) does mentions that:

> A three-year longitudinal study has revealed that some Buddhist
> meditation practitioners are able to willfully induce near-death
> experiences at a pre-planned point in time. Unlike traditional NDEs,
> participants were consciously aware of experiencing the
> meditation-induced NDE and retained control over its content and
> duration.[58] The Dalai Lama has also asserted that experienced
> meditators can deliberately induce the NDE state during meditation,
> being able to recognize and sustain it.[59]

So there are certain medications that can induce OBEs (or roughly, NDEs) too. In the meantime to further research I found a few links on such meditations, one by a Hindu Guru [Swami Sivananda](https://www.sivanandaonline.org/?cmd=displaysection&section_id=1726):

> During the course of practice, one day you will feel that you have
> separated yourself from the body. You will have immense joy mixed with
> fear, joy in the possession of a new, light, astral body, fear owing
> to the entry in a foreign, unknown plane. At the very outset, the new
> consciousness is very rudimentary in the new plane, just as in the
> case of a pup with newly opened eyes in the eighth or tenth day on the
> physical plane.

where he tells the experiences of OBEs.

Unfortunately, he doesn't elaborate on the details of the meditation. I assumed it was particularly meditation on a point between eyebrows and after a month of practice, I don't see any progress particularly here.

I just wish to know what form of meditation in Buddhism (apart from Yoga Nidra Tantra in Hinduism which is basically just hypnosis from sleep) causes OBEs? If my efforts are in the right place.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question does not appear to be about Buddhist philosophy, teaching, and practice, within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: May I know what is it that you are fascinated or curious about? Is it the nature of the soul?

Comment: @DhammaDhatu Apparently I'm asking for the idea about the particular meditation that Buddhists do for NDEs that has been quoted from Wikipedia in the above question.

Comment: @DesmonicaSin I'm curious about the meditation technique that was used to simulate NDEs that I quoted in the question from Wikipedia. I'm afraid that totally seems Buddhist philosophy/meditation-centered question to me. Thank you.

Comment: A meditation technique to achieve NDEs that I understand. What I can't figure out is what do you hope to achieve after you are in near death or out-of-the-body? We don't just hop on a plane to an unknown destination, there is/are thing(s) we want to achieve, what is/are your objective(s)? Can you list them down?

Comment: I don't think there is any Theravadin meditation technique that induced NDEs. In my opinion, the closest to understanding what NDEs using traditional Theravada meditation would be the jhanas. But the traditional objective for attaining the jhanas in Theravada is different from yours. Different objective, belief and mentality results in different experiences and interpretations just as two tourists can go to the same place and see, observe and experience very differently.

Comment: @DesmonicaSin Yes, that I perfectly understand - two people can have different non-physical realms with completely different things. The thing is - I wanted to understand what happens after death, what people see it and what is the experience aftermath. I came to know there are meditations that have similar experiences. So I just wanted to know about the meditations that can help me experience death closer. I don't have any objective or any hope to *achieve anything*, but to experience death as closely before death.

Comment: @DesmonicaSin Okay, so meditations for NDEs differ from meditations for OBEs? In that case I wish to know about both - NDE and OBE meditations to compare things and later evaluate myself how they are different/same/related.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148238/discussion-between-desmonica-sin-and-abhas-kumar-sinha).

Comment: In case you didn't know, HH the Dalai Lama is a Tibetan Buddhist; and it's the Tibetan Buddhist tradition that's responsible for e.g. _The Tibetan Book of the Dead_. So then, I suspect the form of meditation which the Dalai Lama may have been referring to would have been Tibetan -- not Theravadin.

Comment: @ChrisW I too suspect he must be referring to Vajrayana Meditation practices, they too have a lot of overlap with Hinduism because of historical reasons. Unfortunately, the Hindu side doesn't have any documentation of such practices, partly because most of them are esoteric, so I came here to know about it.

Answer (score 1):

Buddhism explains when the mind is free from conceiving self-view, there is no 'death'. This is the goal of Buddhism, namely, the 'Deathless' state. Therefore, there are no meditations in Buddhism to simulate Near-Death Experience because the meditations in Buddhism have the goal of directly experiencing the Deathless.

> The greatest of all gains is health,
>
> Nibbāna is the greatest bliss,
>
> The eightfold path is the best of paths
>
> For it leads safely to the Deathless.
>
> [MN 75](https://suttacentral.net/mn75/en/bodhi?lang=en&reference=none&highlight=false)

> 21. Heedfulness is the path to the Deathless. Heedlessness is the path to death. The heedful die not. The heedless are as if dead already.
>
> [Dhammapada](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.02.budd.html)

> Bhikkhu, ‘I am’ is a conceiving; ‘I am this’ is a conceiving; ‘I shall
> be’ is a conceiving; ‘I shall not be’ is a conceiving; ‘I shall be
> possessed of form’ is a conceiving; ‘I shall be formless’ is a
> conceiving; ‘I shall be percipient’ is a conceiving; ‘I shall be
> non-percipient’ is a conceiving; ‘I shall be
> neither-percipient-nor-non-percipient’ is a conceiving. Conceiving is
> a disease, conceiving is a tumour, conceiving is a dart. By overcoming
> all conceivings, bhikkhu, one is called a sage at peace. And the sage
> at peace is not born, does not age, does not die; he is not shaken and
> does not yearn. For there is nothing present in him by which he might
> be born. Not being born, how could he age? Not ageing, how could he
> die? Not dying, how could he be shaken? Not being shaken, why should
> he yearn?
>
> [MN
> 140](https://suttacentral.net/mn140/en/bodhi?lang=en&reference=none&highlight=false)

> … “Here, bhikkhus, a bhikkhu develops right view … right
> concentration, which has as its final goal the removal of lust, the
> removal of hatred, the removal of delusion….” …
>
> “Here, bhikkhus, a
> bhikkhu develops right view … right concentration, which has the
> Deathless as its ground, the Deathless as its destination, the
> Deathless as its final goal….”
>
> … “Here, bhikkhus, a bhikkhu develops right view … right
> concentration, which slants, slopes, and inclines towards Nibbāna….”
>
> [SN
> 45.139](https://suttacentral.net/sn45.139/en/bodhi?lang=en&reference=none&highlight=false)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for a beautiful question. I can understand why it is disturbing some established buddhist.
After 2500 year human kind had found new terminologies and we struggle to find its root or pointer in tipitak. e.g subcobnscious/unconscious.

Near death is also also one such word. that we can not quote a sutta directly. hence people will try to  oppose you. but thats not right approch.

with my limited knowledge let me try to attempt this.
6 Sense field and Panca upadan Khanda are discussed frequently in tipitak. and what I suggest is what  we call Body is nothing but 6 sense field.  and in meditation, probably after 4th Jhana. you feel similar experience  or death. but actually it is nothing but pacification of 6 sense faculty. mainly the body consciousness is very important because that what we call body. and when it pacifies we feel Death.

There is no speciasl practice for doing this. However extensive practice of samatha will give you this experience. particularly tibetan and hinduism has more answer in this regard.

I had a  series of long discussion with a buddhist who was vedantist earlier and had naturally gone thr  OOB/NDE both.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTaop2T6VYw

Comment: Just to point out, by the first jhana the five senses are no longer perceivable....not until the fourth jhana. In the fourth jhana, the mind sense still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I find this to be a puzzling question in a Buddhist forum. After struggling, I decided to try answering it to the best of my ability.

Most NDEs (be it involving OBEs or not) described by the media tends to be those with wonderful experiences but there are [NDEs that are scary, horrible and frightening](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6173534/). Even in the same individual who had two NDEs years apart, the experiences could be vastly different. Therefore, it is quite certain that every NDE is unique and different people have different NDEs. This is the first puzzling aspect of the question.

The question asked for Buddhist meditation techniques to induce NDEs. Traditionally, jhanas do allow a person to experience meditative bliss where the five senses are no longer perceived. In a way, it is like NDEs as your physical seeing, hearing, smelling, tasting and touching are gone. But it is a blissful and happy state of mind. However, there is no guarantee that a person will experience this joyful state of mind in the actual death experience because there is the element of karma. It will be misleading if a meditation teacher teaches the student that both experiences are similar. This is the second puzzling aspect of the question.

How we deconstruct our experiences affects the way we interpret it. If you read accounts of NDE, it is easy to interpret that something good or bad happened to the soul during NDEs. For Buddhists, we are supposed to train ourselves to understand seeing is merely the seen, hearing is merely the heard…..feeling is merely the felt, perceiving is merely the perceived and so on. The result is that we end up interpreting NDEs very differently.

The moment of death is an important event for Buddhists. All the meditating, practicing and following the Dharma culminate with the goal to understand the craving-to-be i.e. the desire for more experiencing (feelings, perceptions, mental formations and consciousness) as it unfolds during the dying process. As a Buddhist, I understand this *craving-to-be* as the **permanent soul/Atman/self** that non-Buddhists keep harping on. It is this that is with us as we wander through the cycle of death and rebirth and even as I am typing and you are reading. If we penetrate it at the point of dying, an opportunity opens up and we can put an end to it once and for all. But putting an end to the soul/Atman/self would seem ridiculous to a non-Buddhist especially when they are trying to understand it through the perspective of NDEs. This is the last part that I struggle with. With Metta.

Comment: If it is impossible to know what is the experience of NDEs for a person, then how did the wiki article claims that the practitioners were able to induce NDEs?

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha What makes you think the actual death experience will be similar to that of induced NDEs? Can any meditation teacher that teaches you induced NDEs make this guarantee to you?

Comment: No. I don't claim that *actual death experience* would be similar to *meditation induced NDEs*. My question is how the wiki authors/Dalai Lama concluded the experience by meditators were NDEs? If it is so in their properties (which I see by comparison), I wished to know that particular meditation so that I can induce those NDE property in a controlled state.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha I can only answer from my understandings. The similarities between NDEs and the experience of deep meditation is that your physical senses are no longer perceived. But that is as far as the similarities goes, everything else will likely be different. In meditation everything is under your control. However, both NDEs and accidental deaths are not planned, they happened suddenly.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha You have certain pre-conceived ideas about NDEs, do some research on the Internet, you can see for yourself the varieties and differences in NDEs. Lastly, **no one** can guarantee what you will experience in death or near death. Whether you agree or not to this point, may you be happy. With Metta.

Comment: Makes sense. The jhana is similar to meditation in the void in Hinduism using Om, where senses, bodies, and thoughts aren't active. My basic hypothesis is that is is probably the stage when the breathing stops - oxygen level drops below a certain threshold, NDE-like conditions are artificially made, and whatever the thing happens. A lot of meditation pioneers seem to have mastered that stage: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramakrishna's_samadhi